# How to get current page number of pdf document which is rendered using <embed> tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, django, frontend, embed

I am rendering a simple html template in my Django project.
I am using  tag to display the pdf. So, I want to dynamically know which page the user is reading currently.

```
<embed src="sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

Is there any way to get that information, and then use it at the backend.